# Swiper api width is going infinitely

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, swiper.js

is there a bug in swiper when trying to set flex-col direction? the width just goes over board it doesn't stop from becoming larger , if i inspect the page the width is something like '33599999999px'

my code is simple just for testing:

```
"use client"
import { Swiper,SwiperSlide} from 'swiper/react';
import {Pagination,Navigation} from 'swiper/modules';
import 'swiper/css';
import 'swiper/css/pagination';
import 'swiper/css/navigation';

const Testing = () => {
    let arrayOfMonths = ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin','Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','November','Décembre']
    let currentYear = (new Date()).getFullYear();

    const swiperSlides = () => ( arrayOfMonths.map((month,index) => (
        <SwiperSlide key={index} >
            <div className='text-center'>month</div>
        </SwiperSlide>
    )))

    const renderSwiper = () => {
        return (
            <Swiper 
            modules={[Navigation]}
            navigation
            spaceBetween={25}
            slidesPerView={1}
            >
                {swiperSlides()}
            </Swiper>
        )
    }


    return ( 
        <div className='flex flex-col gap-5 mt-5 mx-5 border bg-black md:flex-row'>
            {renderSwiper()}
            {renderSwiper()}
        </div>
     );
}
 
export default Testing;
```

[image: Correct one flex-row]

[image: where the problem occurs flex-col]

Comment: Did it work? Did you eventually figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

A lot of carousel/sliders are a bit buggy about that, and unable to calculate their width properly due to flex.

Generally the fix is to add `width:100%` to the parents of the carousel, or onto the top element of the carousel itself.

Comment: (You don't have a Codepen or anything, so I can't give you exact CSS, but that's the general idea.)

Comment: @Yogi Wrong person. Tell that to OP, not me....